# Passat B6 2009 Fog lights as normal lights

Tags: vw, lights, passat

I have VW Passat B6 2009. I am driving lots when it is dark. I have upgraded my H7 bulbs for new ones which claim 130% brightness but for me it's still not enough.
Sometimes I see cars with much more brightness and I wonder how to make mine the same.

I do not have front fog lights but I have a place for them and I would like to change the fog light to H7 or any other to get more light at the front.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you checked the headlight aim? Are there OEM xenon projectors available for your car? Is there any yellowing on the headlight cover? Fog lights are too low to the ground to provide substantial light without blinding others, so it's probably best to address the headlights themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the qualities that make a good fog light make for a bad driving light. The purpose of the fog light is to help you find the edge of the road in heavy fog. That means a light mounted low with a wide beam and a sharp top cutoff so that it doesn't blind you in the fog.

Instead, start off by checking the aim of your lights and making sure the lenses are in good shape. If you have old plastic lenses that are yellowed and/or scratched you could try a polishing kit or look for glass replacements. The stock lights are decent, especially with good bulbs. You want even light distribution down the road – not a bright spot close to you, that causes too much contrast and makes distant objects harder to see.

If you can it wouldn't be a bad idea to also check the voltage getting to the bulbs, it is possible that your light output is low due to resistance in the circuit somewhere.